# How to copy data from one server to another server in SQL and when ever data changed in Source table the copy must be done into Destination Table

Tags: sql-server

I have source and destination tables. In that almost 30 millions of records are there in Source Table in One server. Now I want to copy this data to another table which is in another server. And at the same time, this copy of data is not once. When ever the data changes in source table , need to insert/update/delete in destination by comparing with a key.

**Solutions that I tried**

Step 1. There is already linked connection between two servers. For inserting data to destination table, I used OPENROWSET function like this for copying data from one server to another server.

```
INSERT INTO destination table 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB', 'provider string', query from source table)
```

Step 2. After this for making recent changes(delta mode) to destination table , I was using MERGE statement

I have created a procedure for step-1 & 2

**Problem**

But the problem is since the data is huge it is taking lot of time (more than 2 hours) for inserting the data and for MERGE statement.

Is anybody aware of how can I achieve this case with in less time. Please suggest

Thanks

Comment: You could use a [trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on your source table

Comment: If you need same table on a different server you can use external tables (if the version of SQL Server is equal or above 2016 (13.x)). [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to docs.ms.com. And there is no need for triggers, inserting/updating etc.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVwxEX5OkqI